# Vscode API: read clipboard text content

Tags: node.js, promise, visual-studio-code, clipboard, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to write an **extension** for **Visual Studio Code**, and I can't manage to understand how to **read the clipboard content**.

The [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Clipboard) specifies this method:

`readText ():Thenable<String>`

Following what I read about `Thenable`, I should be able to get the clipboard's text like that:

```
var clipboard_content = vscode.env.clipboard.readText().then((text)=>text);
```

But all I manage to get is a `Promise { pending }` object.

**What I would like to get** is the clipboard content as a `string`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basics mistake.

Because you use `promises` (async)  and want `async/await` (linear) functionality.

It should be (promises, async code):

```
vscode.env.clipboard.readText().then((text)=>{
    clipboard_content = text; 
    /* code */
});
```

or (sequential code)

```
let clipboard_content = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText(); 
/* code */
```

PS.: In JS, you should use `camelCase` instead of `snake_case` when naming variables and functions. This is one of the recommendations of [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/rules.html)

Comment: Using `await`, I think, doesn't make your code `synchronous` but `sequential`. I would also suggest to replace 'linear' with 'sequential' as a better term to describe sequential events. :-)